# Consume action from different website in ASP MVC controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP MVC controller with action PersonDetails which takes Person object as its parameter. The action is invoked via AJAX call, does some work to validate the Person model and returns a view.

What I'd like to achieve is to validate the model in this action and set some additional params, but then send the object to a different web application (also ASP MVC one) which would make further processing, generate a view and return it as a string. Person model is shared between two apps. Let's assume that I cannot use Web API or WCF instead of the second MVC controller from external app.

Is such scenario possible? What is the best approach when I need to consume action which resides in a different web application from MVC controller, and there is no restful API to use.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you don't need to call the Action from the second web application, maybe this "further processing" functionality can be encapsulated in a common project, then you just need to reference that common project in your first web application in order to accomplish the further processing you want to do